# how to use keytool commands in command line

Tags: keytool

I'm tring to create a google map in my android app
how can i generate a key using the line command?
i didnt find the line command(im using windows os)
i need all the steps until i get the key in order to send it to MD5

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/keytool.html

Comment: It's in your Java installation folder. Mine is C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin. Navigate there using the command line and enter keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore <path_to_debug_keystore>.keystore -storepass android -keypass android